# move values from registers and address

Tags: assembly, emu8086

I try to solve an infinite loop in emu8086 and can't understand the logic behind the actions.

```
 start:
     mov     di, ds:1234h
     mov     bx, [di]
     mov     ax, [bx]
     cmp     ax, 3
     jnz     short start
```

can someone help me understand the logic between all the memory moves?

Comment: What part of the logic is hard to understand?

Comment: `mov     di, ds:1234h` is not valid Intel syntax. I guess it will be compiled as `mov     di, [ds:1234h]`, but would need to check disassembly first to know it. ... In such case it will read `di` value from `[ds:1234h]`, then it will read `bx` value from `[ds:di]` and finally `ax` value from `[ds:bx]`, i.e. three `short*` pointers dereference   `if (3 != (*(*(*ds:1234h)))) goto start` (if you know C)

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume following are the contents of the registers and memory:

`DS` stores `0700`

`DS:1234h` stores `5`

`5` stores `2`

`2` stores `3`

Now the statement

```
mov di, ds:1234h
```

Will transfer `5` to `di`. Because memory address `ds:1234h` ( `0700:1234h` ) stores `5`

And the statement

```
mov  bx, [di]
```

Will transfer `2` to `bx` because data at memory location  (`5`) pointed by `di` stores `2`.

And the statement

```
mov  ax, [bx]
```

Will transfer `3` to `ax` because data at memory location  (`2`) pointed by `di` stores `3`.

And the statement

```
cmp  ax, 3
```

Will set zero flag (Because in our case the contents of `ax` match with `3`)

And lastly the statement

```
jnz  short start
```

Will Jump if zero flag is not set to a label `start` (In our case no jump will be made because zero flag was set in previous statement ). `short` is used for 8bit jump ( there is also 16bit jump know as near jump and a 32bit jump know as far jump [more on here](http://www.electronics.dit.ie/staff/tscarff/program_control/program_control.htm)) .